# Magento 2 Admin- Invalid data provided for linked products

Tags: magento2, php, admin, magento-2.1, related-products

Getting an error

> " Invalid data provided for linked products "

when adding related products to a product from the admin panel and saving

Indexer crons, already setup

Magento CLI version is : 2.1.1

How can I fix it or use database to add the related products ?

I have imported products from Magento 1.9 using the magento data-migration-tool

Also getting error in the admin panel if I move a category from one parent to another, I have to go to database to make the change for that

Comment: have you check data base.
You must check catalog_product_link_attribute && catalog_product_link_type table.

If both of this tables are empty then drop them and import those table from fresh magento 2 setup.