# Magento 2.3: Error Assigning Related Products

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, related-products

Trying to add some related / cross-sell and upsells to products in the admin but receiving the following error after saving the product:

> The linked products data is invalid. Verify the data and try again.

I checked my exception log and saw this:

```
main.CRITICAL: The linked products data is invalid. Verify the data and try again. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\CouldNotSaveException(code: 0): The linked products data is invalid. Verify the data and try again. at /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductLink/Repository.php:141)"} []
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: did it happen to all or only for specific products?

Comment: I haven't tested every product but so far every product we've tried we receive that error when trying to assign a related / upsell / crossell product

Comment: did you chrck this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147183/magento-2-admin-invalid-data-provided-for-linked-products

Comment: oh I see, I'll try that.. both of my tables are empty as that comment describes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to fix this:

First check the following tables in your DB:

`catalog_product_link_attribute` and `catalog_product_link_type`

If those are empty, you need to run the following SQL queries:

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_link_attribute` (`product_link_attribute_id`, `link_type_id`, `product_link_attribute_code`, `data_type`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'position', 'int'),
(2, 4, 'position', 'int'),
(3, 5, 'position', 'int'),
(4, 3, 'position', 'int'),
(5, 3, 'qty', 'decimal');

INSERT INTO `catalog_product_link_type` (`link_type_id`, `code`) VALUES
(1, 'relation'),
(3, 'super'),
(4, 'up_sell'),
(5, 'cross_sell');
```

Comment: Thanks, its worked for me, please run query in reverse order else it will throw foreign key exception

Comment: hello , i checked in my database already same tables  with these data. how to  resolve this error ?

Comment: what if we get this error while the tables are properly populated ? :/

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I get this message while the database is already correct. So what then?